# Using Keyboard as and Input Device on C# Calculator

Tags: c#

So i have a working calculator written in C# (complete code included below) and i can only input numbers and symbols using the calculators buttons. I would like to be able to use the keyboard and the buttons as input devices. My problem is i dont know how since i have only been learning c# for a week. I would like one of you who are much more experienced and smarter than me to write that code :) Complete calculator program included and thank you in advanced.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "1";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "2";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "3";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "4";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "5";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "6";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "7";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "8";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = ""; 
            input += "9";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "undefined";
                }

            }
        }      

         private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "0";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '*';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '+';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;

        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '-';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '/';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google it and you will get lots of examples to create calculator using c#.

Comment: I have the calculator i just need the code that would allow me to use the keyboard as an input device.

Comment: Is this program not allows you using keyboard?

Comment: Correct hence my question....

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Considering the above code essentially **works without problem**; your post is essentially a `set of requirements`, it is arguably is **off-topic** for this site sadly.  Consider posting an attempt at `keybinding` or `keyboard shortcuts`.  This will help us help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `KeyDown` event:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

... or the `KeyPress` event (depending on how you want to handle things): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

...and `Keys` enumeration:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You'll need to handle the `KeyDown` event appropriately (or `KeyPress` if you choose that), as shown in the example below:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Don't forget to subscribe to the event:

```
this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a KeyPressEventHandler and assign a method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
        string operand1 = string.Empty;
        string operand2 = string.Empty;
        char operation;
        double result = 0.0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.KeyPress +=
                new KeyPressEventHandler(Form1_KeyPress);
        }

        void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //keypressed
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.KeyChar);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "1";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "2";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "3";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "4";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "5";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "6";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "7";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "8";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "9";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            operand2 = input;
            double num1, num2;
            double.TryParse(operand1, out num1);
            double.TryParse(operand2, out num2);

            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;

            if (operation == '+')
            {
                result = num1 + num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '-')
            {
                result = num1 - num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '*')
            {
                result = num1 * num2;
                textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            else if (operation == '/')
            {
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "undefined";
                }

            }
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            this.input = string.Empty;
            this.operand1 = string.Empty;
            this.operand2 = string.Empty;
        }

        private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            input += "0";
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '*';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '+';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;

        }

        private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '-';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }

        private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = "";
            operand1 = input;
            operation = '/';
            input = string.Empty;
            this.textBox1.Text += input;
        }
    }
}
```

To get which key was pressed use

```
e.KeyChar
```